# What else can interrupt uploads using busboy on node v18?

Tags: node.js, upload, multipartform-data, form-data, busboy

I am using latest Busboy and I am aware of the readme where it says:

"Note: If you are using node v18.0.0 or newer, please be aware of the node.js HTTP(S) server's requestTimeout configuration setting that is now enabled by default, which could cause upload interruptions if the upload takes too long." source: https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#readme

I tried to disable these:

```
server.requestTimeout = 0;
server.headerTimeout = 0; 
server.keepAliveTimeout = 0;
```

And for different file extensions the interrupt is different,
ex:
for rar file of 50MB is interrupted at 10%
for msi file of 90MB is interrupted at 80%

At frontend I create FormData and send it using XMLHttpRequest. Before I used node 12.